# How to Dynamically update multiple PivotCaches in one workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Every month, I run a massive Scorecard report.  The raw data contains 13 workbooks that are exported as .csv files.

I use Power Query to manipulate and Append this data into 4 different worksheets.
To keep things clean, I then use a Macro to move the 4 Data Arrays into a Scorecard Workbook (which is shared with the team)

The Scorecard Workbook has 4 tabs with the Data Sheets: `wsTotalUS`, `wsCombined`, `wsDFCoreMkts`, `wsNovCoreMkts`.

The `4 Data Sheets` to create `4 different Pivot Caches`.

`wsTotalUS` has a Pivot Table on `Sheet5`

`wsCombined` has a Pivot Table on `Sheets 6-13`

`wsDFCoreMkts` has a Pivot Table on `Sheet 14`

`wsNovCoreMkts` has a Pivot Table on `Sheet 15`

Each month the data `Rows` can change (The Columns will always be the same - “A:AP”)

I have researched how to dynamically update pivot tables.  I know some articles suggest changing the source data into a Table.  I would like to avoid this due to the amount of time it would take to move the Data over to the Scorecard.

For example: `wsTotalUS` has 47,707 rows & `wsCombined` has 123,153 rows

One article I found had the code written on the Source Data Sheet as a Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate().
However, this would only use one Data Sheet, and update all of the Pivot Tables in the workbook when you switch from the data sheet.
[How to Dynamically Update All Pivot Tables Data Source in Excel](https://www.exceltip.com/excel-pivot-tables/how-to-dynamically-update-all-pivot-tables-data-source-in-excel.html)

I found these articles, but they one only refers to one Data Sheet and one Pivot Table.
[How to Automatically Update a Pivot Table Range in Excel](https://excelchamps.com/blog/auto-update-pivot-table-range/#3)
[Dynamically Change a Pivot Table's Data Source Range with This VBA Code](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/7/9/change-a-pivot-tables-data-source-range)

This article uses the Worksheet_SelectionChange event.  But again, only one Data Sheet is implied here.
[Refresh Pivot Tables Automatically when Source Data Changes](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/refresh-pivot-tables-automatically/)

How do I go about dynamically updating 4 different PivotCaches within a workbook?
Should I just run 4 separate sub routines?

UPDATED:

Based on Tim's suggestion:

Under Formulas -> Named Range:
`TotalUS =OFFSET('Total US'!$A$1,0,0, COUNTA('Total US'!$A:$A),COUNTA('Total US'!$1:$1))`

Then go to the Pivot Table that references this data, Change Data Source = `TotalUS`

Comment: Have you considered creating dynamic names pointing at each table and using the names as the source for your pivot caches?

Comment: @TimWilliams when you say 'dynamic names pointing at each table'.. Do you mean pointing creating a dynamic named range for each of the 4 Data sheets?   Referring to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-dynamic-defined-range

Comment: @TimWilliams I also found this source saying =OFFSET recalculates with every change to a worksheet, which could be slow for large data sets.  And to consider using =INDEX instead.  Thoughts?  https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-offset  & https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index

Comment: Doesn't sound like your datasets (once imported) will really change much?  And you only have one formula per named range, so not much overhead to add...

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated my OP with the steps suggested.  Does this look about right?